# ¿se puede crear una clave foránea con auto incremento? Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente caso que me ha planteado una empresa para un proyecto: En una base de datos, tengo X tablas que conectan con una llamada "Documento" con la clave primaria "numeroDocumento", el objetivo de esta tabla es llevar un conteo de cada nuevo elemento a las tablas anteriores.

La idea es que, por ejemplo, si registro un nuevo usuario al sistema, que pertenecería a la tabla "usuarios", se le asignaría el numero de documento actual disponible (ej: 21.325) y al confirmar el registro, dicha clave automáticamente se le sumaria +1 para llevar el conteo, haciendo que en caso de crear un usuario justo después del anterior, su numero de documento seria 21.326, y así; esto aplica para todas las tablas a las que este asignado el numero de documento, por ejemplo, una que se encargue de crear reportes, registros de empresas, etc.

Mi problema radica en que no se como hacer esto dentro de la base de datos, o de si quiera si es posible, la idea es que se estructure de una forma similar a esto:

```
t_Documento

PK_numeroDocumento


t_Usuario

PK_CDI
FK_numeroDocumento


t_Reporte

PK_NumeroReporte
FK_numeroDocumento
```

Intente hacerlo de esta forma, pero no crea el numero de documento en la tabla de documento, cosa sin la cual no se podría llevar el conteo.

EDIT: El objetivo de la tabla t_documento es que cada tabla a la que su clave principal este enlazado como una foránea lo incremente en uno, es decir, si tengo por ejemplo 3 tablas, y cada una tiene respectivametne 30, 40 y 15 registros, entonces mi tabla de documentos deberia tener 85 registros totales, pues suma +1 por cada registro realizado en las tablas enlazadas, no es un simple auto incremento de una PK.

las tablas que manejo enlazadas con documentos son las siguientes:

```
empleado
|PK empleadoCodigo
|
|FK documento
CONSTRAINT `fkempleado_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`),

propuesta
|PK idPropuesta
|
|FK documento
CONSTRAINT `fkpropuesta_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,

proyecto
|PK idProyecto
|
|FK documento
CONSTRAINT `fkproyecto_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`),

patrocinante
|PK patrocinanteRIF
|
|FK documento
CONSTRAINT `fkpatrocinante_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,

contacto
|PK contactoCI
|
|FK documento
 CONSTRAINT `fkcontacto_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`),

inversiones
|PK idInversion
|
|FK documento
CONSTRAINT `fkInversiones_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`documento`)
    REFERENCES `superatec2`.`documento` (`documento`)
```

Aqui el [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jw14LXBF) pero es bastante largo ya que la Base de datos contiene muchos elementos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero la autonumerica estaria en t_documento no? y de ahi se exporta a los otros lugares?

Comment: hola, lo que necesitas es un `trigger` (disparador) `after insert` (después de insertar) para cada tabla donde quieras llevar un conteo de cada nuevo registro, o sea en t_Usuario y t_Reporte. Pero deberías agregar información de la estructura de tus tablas así te ayudamos a crear los triggers

Comment: @JuanRom Hey genial, bueno, déjame edito para dar más información sobre las tablas principales, contienen una gran cantidad de atributos y realmente lo que busco es que se haga el conteo automatico en la PK de documento cuando una tabla enlazada a esta se le haga un registro, así que intentare ponerlo con la información que pueda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo la pregunta ya editada es **before insert**. Hice solo tres tablas: `documento, empleado, proyecto`, a modo de ejemplo, el resto de los triggers son idénticos, para que los hagas vos.
Acá va el script que me generó el Workbench para que crees la base de datos:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ej_foranea_autoincrement
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ej_foranea_autoincrement` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `ej_foranea_autoincrement` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`documento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`documento` (
  `id_documento` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `fecha_hora` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_documento`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`proyecto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`proyecto` (
  `id_proyecto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `id_documento` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_proyecto`, `id_documento`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_proyecto_documento1_idx` (`id_documento` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_proyecto_documento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_documento`)
    REFERENCES `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`documento` (`id_documento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`empleado`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`empleado` (
  `id_empleado` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `id_documento` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_empleado`, `id_documento`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_empleado_documento_idx` (`id_documento` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_empleado_documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_documento`)
    REFERENCES `ej_foranea_autoincrement`.`documento` (`id_documento`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Luego ejecutas este código (de a uno por vez) para crear el **trigger**:

- Trigger de tabla empleado:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER empleado_BI BEFORE INSERT ON empleado
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- insertamos registro en documento con fecha y hora actual
    insert into documento(fecha_hora) values(now());
    -- seteamos el campo id_documento de empleado con el último id de documento
    set new.id_documento =(select max(id_documento) from documento);
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

- Trigger de tabla proyecto:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER proyecto_BI BEFORE INSERT ON proyecto
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- insertamos registro en documento con fecha y hora actual
    insert into documento(fecha_hora) values(now());
    -- seteamos el campo id_documento de proyecto con el último id de documento
    set new.id_documento =(select max(id_documento) from documento);
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Insertas en `empleado` sin valores tanto en `id_empleado` como en `id_documento`.
Insertas en `proyecto` sin valores tanto en `id_proyecto` como en `id_documento`.
Y ya verás como se insertan registros en `documento`
Acá muestro mis resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Diagrama de Workbench:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijate que el tipo de relación es `uno a uno con linea continua`

Answer (score 1):

para que si cuando insertas un registro el numero de fk va ser igual a la pk de documento practicamente la pk de documento seria el que se incremente y la fk seria el mismo numero asi identificas que documento le pertenece a cada usuario

Comment: Hola, el objetivo es que la clave "documento" sume +1 por cada registro de cada tabla enlazada, es decir, no esta enlazada solo a una tabla, si hay por ejemplo 30 registros de empleados, 40 reportes y 20 proyectos, en total serian 70 documentos, por lo que muy factiblemente, se puede dar el caso de un empleado que sea el numero 200 de la empresa, pero posea el registro de documento numero 3.521 por dar un caso hipotético. Sin embargo tu razonamiento tampoco esta mal.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes modificar el software, simplemente antes de que se inserte un registro en alguna tabla primero haces un insert en la t_Documento y luego en la tabla que toque (usuarios, albaranes, o la que sea) haces el insert con la FK igual a la PK_numeroDocumento. Si no puedes modificar el software seguramente con triggers puedas hacerlo (Puedes poner que se ejecuten automáticamente cada vez que se ejecuta un insert por ejemplo y que primero se haga el insert en la t_Documento y después en la que se iba a hacer originalmente ya con el autonumérico asignado).

Suerte y saludos.